gitversion/execute does not tag anything
I am have added GitTools into Azure Devops extension to work with GitVersion utility. However, this utility does not tag my processing commit/branch as expected.
- task: gitversion/setup@3.0.0
  displayName: Install GitVersion
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '6.x'
- task: gitversion/command@3.0.0
  displayName: 'GitVersion@command: Determine Version & Output the FullSemVer variable'
  name: gitversioning_init # for reference
  inputs:
    updateGitTagVersion: true
    printAllVariables: true
    preferBundledVersion: true    
    arguments: '/showvariable SemVer /showvariable FullSemVer' # /showConfig'
    targetPath: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/${{ parameters.RepoPath }}'
    overrideConfig: |
      update-build-number=true

- task: gitversion/execute@3.0.0
  name: gitversioning # for reference
  displayName: 'GitVersion@execute'
  inputs:
    updateAssemblyInfo: false
    updateGitTagVersion: true
    printAllVariables: true
    preferBundledVersion: true
    targetPath: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/${{ parameters.RepoPath }}'
  condition: succeeded()

The first bit: gitversion/command@3.0.0 seems to be useless as it only otputs the version variable. The second command: gitversion/execute@3.0.0 produces a set of various GitVersion variables to env that I can capture in the next steps and use for manual tagging, but this is an extra step and hassle.

I tried removing GitVersion.yaml from the repository - same effect
Does it have limitations for tagging only within certain stage of pipeline (I am launching it within CI)?


The pipeline will fetch your code to agent and execute the task. The gitverion doesn't tag commits or branches in remote devops repo. You can push the tag if needed in pipeline. I also added the info about GitVersion.yml. Please let me  know if you have any queries.

It does not tag even locally, only producing variables. I had to add "git tag" command separately as a script

Yes, i also include  the git tag sample in the yaml below, please have a check, let me know if you have any queries, thanks.

The gitversion tasks will not automatically tag commits or branches in your DevOps repository, but they do calculate and provide version information based on your Git history, which you can then use to create tags as part of your pipeline process.
The GitVersion.yml is used in gitversion/execute@3 task, you can specify the task with parameter as below.
- task: gitversion/execute@3
  name: gitversioning # for reference
  displayName: 'GitVersion@execute'
  inputs:
    useConfigFile: true
    configFilePath: 'GitVersion.yml'
  condition: succeeded()

You can define custom expression in GitVersion.yml, it will be applied during the task then. I changed the version expression in GitVersion.yml and applied to task as below:

The gitversion/command@3 is used to run specific GitVersion command, typically used to output specific version variables, you can check the doc for the details. You can remove the task if it's not needed.
There are some parameters are not needed in your command and execute task, please click on the task, select correct parameter from right side, click add button to save.

For more details, please check the link where has some examples.
My sample yaml for your reference:
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
  persistCredentials: true    #<--- persist credential so that can push the tag to devops repo

- task: gitversion/setup@3
  displayName: Install GitVersion
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.x'

- task: gitversion/command@3
  displayName: 'GitVersion@command: Determine Version & Output the FullSemVer variable'
  name: gitversioning_init # for reference
  inputs:
    disableShallowCloneCheck: true
    arguments: '/showvariable SemVer /showvariable FullSemVer'

- task: gitversion/execute@3
  name: gitversioning # for reference
  displayName: 'GitVersion@execute'
  inputs:
    useConfigFile: true
    configFilePath: 'GitVersion.yml'
  condition: succeeded()

- script: |
    git tag $(GitVersion.MajorMinorPatch)
    git push origin $(GitVersion.MajorMinorPatch)    #<-- push tag to repo
  displayName: 'Tag sources with version'

I downgrade gitversion to version 5 since it will fail with version 6 when Gitversion.yml added, it's reported in issue here.
I pushed the version to tag at the last, make sure the Build service account grant contribute permission on the repo.


